# T-SQL query for summarizing data by month using 2 date fields

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with Volume, OpenDate, and CloseDate fields. I need to summarize the Volume data by month counting it once in the month it was opened and again in the month it was closed. I can't figure out the correct way to incorporate both dates into the grouping and the conditional date check to use within the SUM() functions.

```
OpenDate        Volume  CloseDate
1/1/2016 00:00  8,000   1/1/2016 00:00
1/3/2016 00:00  10,000  2/3/2016 00:00
1/4/2016 00:00  20,000  Null
2/1/2016 00:00  8,000   2/5/2016 00:00
2/3/2016 00:00  10,000  3/1/2016 00:00
2/5/2016 00:00  20,000  Null

Expected Results    
Month       Volume
1/1/2016    46,000
2/1/2016    56,000
3/1/2016    10,000


    SELECT CAST(
           CAST(YEAR(OpenDate) AS VARCHAR(4) ) +
           '-' +
           CAST(MONTH(OpenDate)AS VARCHAR(2))  + 
           '-01'
           AS DATETIME) MonthYear,
           SUM (Volume) + 
           SUM( CASE WHEN CloseDate IS NOT NULL AND CloseDate = ???
                     THEN Volume
                     ELSE 0 
                 END
               )  Volume
      FROM ORDERS 
  GROUP BY CAST(
           CAST(YEAR(OpenDate) AS VARCHAR(4) ) +
           '-' +
           CAST(MONTH(OpenDate)AS VARCHAR(2))  + 
           '-01'
           AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: Why 46,000? I calculated 38,000...

Comment: the first record with 8,000 is counted twice in January cause it's opened and closed in the same month

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `union all` and swap `OpenDate` with `CloseDate` like so:

```
select 
    OpenDate = convert(varchar(10),dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, OpenDate )  , 0),120)
  , Volumne = sum(Volume)
from (
  select OpenDate, Volume 
  from t
  union all 
  select CloseDate, Volume 
  from t
  where CloseDate is not null
  ) s
group by dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, OpenDate )  , 0)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZGZT62294

returns:

```
+------------+---------+
|  OpenDate  | Volumne |
+------------+---------+
| 2016-01-01 |   46000 |
| 2016-02-01 |   56000 |
| 2016-03-01 |   10000 |
+------------+---------+
```